# What to do with axon-server error [AXONIQ-2100] during upgrade to axon-server version 2023.1.2

Tags: axon

We are upgrading a single node axon-server from version 4.* to 2023.1.2
This server is running the free version, so without license.

During the upgrade we get:
`100   153  100    34  100   119    326   1144 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1471 [AXONIQ-2100] No leader for _admin`

Does someone know what the cause is and how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Try running with following env property set:

```
AXONIQ_AXONSERVER_STANDALONE=true
```

Comment: Thanks @schananas for the quick en correct answer